# Python-Pandas url request not returning all data

Tags: python

I'm trying to get all the weather data from a website, but for some reason, I am not getting all the data. In the middle of the returned data, there are four missing lines. I'm missing lines 30-33.

```
import pandas as pd
url2 = 'http://www.intellicast.com/Local/Observation.aspx?unit=F&location=USMS0371'

data2 = pd.read_html(url2)
```

Comment: You are not missing them at all. It's the way the dataframe is printed when you call it. You can change the display settings with `import pandas as pd; pd.set_option('max_rows',1000); data2`. You should see all the rows printed.

Comment: Also your `pd.read_html()` call returns two dataframes and you want select the second one: `data2 = pd.read_html(url2,header=0)[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I've done both!

Comment: I will add it as the answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows are not missing. They are hidden by pandas because of the display settings. You can change the display settings with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_rows',100) #To display 100 rows
```

Also, the output of the call returns 2 dataframes and you want the second one. So, do the following to get the right dataframe:

```
data2 = pd.read_html(url2,header=0)[1]
```

You can display it by just calling it.

```
data2
```

Hope this helps.